# Reading a single element from a tuple (containing 2 elements) within a list (containing several tuples)

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list containing tupels, i.e.

```
df = [('apa', 'apc'), ('apa', 'bp'), ('br', 'bpt')]
```

with

```
df[0]
```

I would get

```
('apa', 'apc')
```

How could I get 'apa' only from that tuple?

Comment: `df[0][0]`? I'm not sure if that's your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
a, b = df[0]
```

which in case of your data would set value of `a` to `apa` and `b` to `apc`. If you want just to get `apa` from your tuple, then refer as you'd with lists:

```
a = df[0][0]
```